# Java доступ к методам родительского класса

Tags: java, ооп, наследование, инкапсуляция

Как сделать так чтоб метод был доступен только в текущем и наследуемом классе в Java. Спасибо)

Comment: в арсенале джавы есть 4 модификатора доступа, посему никак. наиболе приближенный - protected, тогда метод смогут использовать все наследники , сам класс, но , помимо этого, еще все классы, находящиеся в одном пакете.

Comment: а ты просто не используй их нигде кроме того, где тебе надо)

Comment: как ниже написали сделать метод protected, а класс наследник final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать модификатор protected и держать родительский класс и классы наследники в отдельном пакете или использовать интерфейс